# WooCommerce change single product link

Tags: php, wordpress

By default WooCommerce creates a product page link and add it into the feature image (and the title as well) once you have created one . 
I will like to change just a single product's link without affecting the others.
In the cart.php file I see these lines:

```
<td class="product-name">
                    <?php // Avada edit ?>
                    <span class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                            if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                                echo $thumbnail;
                            else
                                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $thumbnail );
                        ?>
                    </span>
                    <div class="product-info">
                    <?php
                        if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        else
                            // Avada edit
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a class="product-title" href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

I know that if I modify the `else` line on the `<span class="product-thumbnail">` section for this one:

```
sprintf( '%s', $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

I can remove the links, but this affect to all products.

How can I call the ID product and then change its link? I know it will be with `$_product->id` but after that I don't know how or where to place it.

PS:please excuse my English and thank you.

Comment: Do you know the `id` of the product you want to mess with

Comment: Of course, the `id` is 606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can add other products create an array, currently only containing one `id`, but who knows what the future brings

```
$special_products = array(606);
```

Then just add another test in this code and then output whatever you want instead of what was done before

```
if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) {
   echo $thumbnail;
} else {
    if ( in_array($_product->id, $special_products) ) {
        echo 'Something else, whatever you like';
    } else {
        printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $thumbnail );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Riggs for your quick answer!!! I really appreciate it but I think I didn't explain myself correctly.

Comment: What I need is to take the user to a different page instead that the one WooCommerce creates. When you click on the product it will take you to the product page by default. I want to change that. Nothing else.

Comment: Well thats what you put in `echo 'Something else, whatever you like';` Or is that a request for me to guess where you want to send the user

Comment: This is the site [link](http://powerupwedge.flywheelsites.com/) because it is hosted in flywheel you need the password which is username:flywheel and pass:amused-credit.

Comment: if you go to the shop section, you can see that the 1st product says Customize your Wedge and below Start design, I want the image and the first title to link customer to the page of start design without changing anythin

Comment: Do you know what I'm saying @RiggisFolly

Comment: Well good luck with that. I told you how to do it, I am not going to do it for you

Comment: Absolutely! I just wanted to make sure that was all. Thank you @RiggsFolly